# RichFaces problem with ajax commandButton

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces

Hi i have a problem with `<a4j:commandButton>`
after i press it for some reason all buttons on this page are changing their style

any suggestions would be much appretiated
i have uploaded a video which shows my problem @ 0:10 sec
http://www.screencast.com/users/Schyzotrop/folders/Jing/media/b54aece2-4a97-45dc-99eb-76a7fbe29002
**thanks**

```
        <a4j:form id="form" ajaxSubmit="true">
            <a4j:commandButton id="butNC" limitToList="true" action="#{category.createSetup}" value="New Category" />
            <a4j:commandButton reRender="catDataScroller" onclick=""></a4j:commandButton>
            <rich:dataTable id="categoryList" value="#{category.categoryItems}"
                            var="item" rows="10" width="100%">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Listing Category Items" />
                </f:facet>
                <rich:column width="10%" style="text-align:center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column width="75%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Description"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{item.description}"/>
                </rich:column>
                <rich:column style="text-align:center">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Actions"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Show" action="#{category.detailSetup}">
                        <f:param name="jsfcrud.currentCategory" value="#{jsfcrud_class['classes.util.JsfUtil'].jsfcrud_method['getAsConvertedString'][item][category.converter].jsfcrud_invoke}"/>
                    </a4j:commandButton>
                    <h:outputText value=" "/>
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Edit" action="#{category.editSetup}">
                        <f:param name="jsfcrud.currentCategory" value="#{jsfcrud_class['classes.util.JsfUtil'].jsfcrud_method['getAsConvertedString'][item][category.converter].jsfcrud_invoke}"/>
                    </a4j:commandButton>
                    <h:outputText value=" "/>
                    <a4j:commandButton value="Destroy" limitToList="true" action="#{category.destroy}" type="submit">
                        <%--<f:param name="jsfcrud.currentCategory" value="#{jsfcrud_class['classes.util.JsfUtil'].jsfcrud_method['getAsConvertedString'][item][category.converter].jsfcrud_invoke}"/>--%>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.categoryID}"/>
                        <h:outputText value=" #{jsfcrud_class['classes.util.JsfUtil'].jsfcrud_method['getAsConvertedString'][item][category.converter].jsfcrud_invoke}"/>
                        <f:param name="catID" value="#{item.categoryID}"/>
                    </a4j:commandButton>
                </rich:column>
            </rich:dataTable>
            <rich:spacer height="30" />
            <rich:datascroller id="catDataScroller" for="categoryList" maxPages="10"/>
            <rich:messages style="color:red"></rich:messages>
        </a4j:form>
```

Comment: i think it is 3.3.0 
adding screenshot of libraries... 
http://screencast.com/t/NmZiZjY3ZGM

Comment: Have you tried specifying `a4j:region`'s around the elements that you want re-rendered on ajax action?

Comment: the problem seems to be that when re-rendered, the styles aren't loaded

Comment: which makes me ask - what are your script and style loading strategies?

Comment: i am new to richfaces technology and J2EE and to be honest i have no idea what do u mean by script/style loading strategies...
can u suggest me some sources where i can find any information about them?
probably i don't have any "loading strategy" at all. i was asuming framework will do this for me

but still if styles were lost completly why tables are still formated as they should? only buttons are losing their styles

Answer (score 0):

On loading of rich:dataTable it simply assigns the default styleClass of a4j:commandButton, but when you clicking all the buttons set to default css styles. You are not mentioned styleClass attribute for a4j:commmandButton.

For example take this as an example.

```
<a4j:commandButton value="Confirm" styleClass="buttonstyle prisefont15" style="width:100px; height:30px; cursor:pointer;" action="#{DraftZoneBean.confirmAction}" immediate="true" reRender="draftzoneForm">
                                                                </a4j:commandButton>
```